# Sharepoint site created from a Team: cannot retrieve original Owners Group

Tags: sharepoint-online, permissions, microsoft-teams

Someone has previously messed up permissions in a SharePoint site created from Teams. Despite the fact that the  Owners group is there in the SP permissions and works, I am unable to add it in Site Collection Admins as it is normally for sites that are created from Teams. Is this normal behavior?

The permissions seems disconnected as in the Team/Group permission I see only one person while in the Site there are many people.

Could it be that this was a standalone classic site and later it was attached to an existing group/team? In this case how you 'connect' the members of the team with the members of the site?

Answer (score 0):

The site created from Microsoft Teams is SharePoint Online team site which connected to Office 365 Group. There is an Office 365 group created when the Microsoft Teams creates a site.

It’s different from team site which created in SharePoint admin center. So it’s normal behavior that we are unable to add the site owner group to site collection admins

Comment: I am not 100% sure that it was created as a Team site from admin center and later attached. However, I can add the <sitename> members group to Site collection admin, this is what triggered my doubt, when i search for the site name I only get the members group and not the owners. Why is that?